# search and remove a string if it is part of another string in R

Tags: r, nlp, substring

I have a data frame in R with the following text column

```
<strings>
sentence
this is
this is a sentence
outlook
microsoft outlook
```

I want to search and remove the strings in this column that are a substring of another string. 
My output should be

```
<strings>
this is a sentence
microsoft outlook
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create test data:

```
tt <- c("sentence", "this is", "this is a sentence", "outlook", "microsoft outlook")
```

2.Suggested solution using base `sapply` and `grepl`:
We check for each element `tt[i]` in 'tt' if it appears *any*where in `tt[-i]` i.e. if it appears *any*where in the rest of the list. We then negate the result using `!` and use the resulting vector from `sapply` as a logical index for the original list:

```
tt[sapply(seq_along(tt), function(x) !any(grepl(tt[x], tt[-x])))]
```

Returns:

```
> [1] "this is a sentence" "microsoft outlook"
```